# Java Generics : Syntax Explanation

Tags: java, generics

I am new to java generics my question is :

```
public static < E > void printArray( E[] inputArray )
```

In the above statement when the return type of function is void then why we have used `E` before `void`? Why this syntax is valid ?

As per theory a method could itself be an return type?

```
Then suppose E = method_abc then how compiler will manage

public static method_abc void printArray (E[] Array)
```

My reference program was

```
public class GenericMethodTest
{
   // generic method printArray                         
   public static < E > void printArray( E[] inputArray )
   {
      // Display array elements              
         for ( E element : inputArray ){        
            System.out.printf( "%s ", element );
         }
         System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        // Create arrays of Integer, Double and Character
        Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Double[] doubleArray = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
        Character[] charArray = { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O' };

        System.out.println( "Array integerArray contains:" );
        printArray( intArray  ); // pass an Integer array

        System.out.println( "\nArray doubleArray contains:" );
        printArray( doubleArray ); // pass a Double array

        System.out.println( "\nArray characterArray contains:" );
        printArray( charArray ); // pass a Character array
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<E>` here has nothing to do with the return type; it means that this is a generic function which can take various types of arrays. To be easier to understand, the code could be something like this:

```
public class GenericMethodTest
{
   // generic method printArray                         
   public static < E > void printArray( E[] inputArray )
   {
      // Display array elements              
         for ( E element : inputArray ){        
            System.out.printf( "%s ", element );
         }
         System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        // Create arrays of Integer, Double and Character
        Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Double[] doubleArray = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
        Character[] charArray = { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O' };

        System.out.println( "Array integerArray contains:" );
        GenericMethodTest.<Integer>printArray( intArray  ); // pass an Integer array

        System.out.println( "\nArray doubleArray contains:" );
        GenericMethodTest.<Double>printArray( doubleArray ); // pass a Double array

        System.out.println( "\nArray characterArray contains:" );
        GenericMethodTest.<Character>printArray( charArray ); // pass a Character array
    } 
}
```

So what the `<E>` does it tell the function *"There is a generic type `E` and you accept arrays of `E`, so if for example I call you with the generic type `Integer` you accept `Integer[]`."*

It does **not** change the return type though. Just like `public static` doesn't change the return type.

Comment: [Blalasaadri] Sir Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

In `public static < E > void printArray( E[] inputArray )`,
the `E` is just used to signify a Generic parameter. The return type of the method is still `void`.

Comment: [Rrevo] Sir Than you :)

Answer (score 1):

By `<E>` you define a generic variable type, if you will write

```
public static void printArray( E[] inputArray )
```

Java will try to find a class with name `E`, because you don't define `E` as a generic.
The return value in both cases are null, this `<E>` generic definition part in not a part of return value, it's a separate block of function signature.

Comment: [Dmitry Spikhalskiy] Thank you sir :)